# Propertyregex to read a CSV line and assign fields to variables

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I have a csv/txt file with below entries

```
abc,123
xyz,678
ijk,921
```

I'm trying to read the file through for loop and assign first element to var1, and second to var2

```
var1=abc
var2=123
```

I need to use these variables to perform some task and return back to the loop to read the next line of the file and assign new values.

Below is what I have, and I'm not able to assign the variable

```
<loadfile property="message" srcFile="test.txt" />

<target name="compile">
  <for param="line" list="${message}" delimiter="${line.separator}">
    <sequential>
      <echo>@{line}</echo>
      <propertyregex property="var1"
                     input="@line"
                     regexp="/^(.+?),(.+)/"
                     select="\1" />
      <echo message="${var1}" />
    </sequential>
  </for>
</target>
```

Below is the output I get, showing no assignment of value to var1.

```
     [echo] abc,123
     [echo] ${var1}
     [echo] xyz,678
     [echo] ${var1}
     [echo] ijk,921
     [echo] ${var1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of errors, the below loop body works for me, see output at the end.

The first problem is that the `@{line}` parameter substitution syntax in the [`for` loop](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html) uses an antcontrib macrodef, and the `{}` brakets are not optional - you had missed them out of the `input=""` attribute, whereas in the `echo` task you had included them.

The second problem is that you need not specify enclosing slashes `/../` in the `rexexp=` attribute.

```
<echo>@{line}</echo>
<propertyregex property="var1"
                    override="yes"
                    input="@{line}"
                    regexp="^(.+?),(.+)"
                    select="\1"/>
<propertyregex property="var2"
                    override="yes"
                    input="@{line}"
                    regexp="^(.+?),(.+)"
                    select="\2"/>
<echo message="${var1},${var2}" />
```

Output:

```
 [echo] abc,123
 [echo] abc,123
 [echo] xyz,678
 [echo] xyz,678
 [echo] ijk,921
 [echo] ijk,921
```